# String from table inside new string query

Tags: java, android, sqlite

i got this code:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_clicked);
    String query = "SELECT ROWID _id, linie"
            + " FROM linie";

    ArrayList<String> HaltestellenListe = CursorToArray(getApplicationContext(), query, new String[] {});

    final ListView lvD = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lvClicked);


    ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.activity_clicked, R.id.tvClicked, HaltestellenListe);
    lvD.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
    lvD.setDividerHeight(8);



    lvD.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() { 
             @Override
             public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                  String linie = lvD.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();

                 }
        });






}

public ArrayList<String> CursorToArray(Context ApplicationContext, String query, String[] whereClause){
    ArrayList<String> ArrayList = new ArrayList<String>();

    DataBaseHelper dbHelper = new DataBaseHelper(getBaseContext());

    Cursor c = dbHelper.dbHelper(ApplicationContext).rawQuery(query, whereClause);
    dbHelper.close();

    c.moveToFirst();


    while (!c.isAfterLast()){

        if (c.isNull(c.getColumnIndex("linie")) == false){
            ArrayList.add(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("linie")));  
        }


        c.moveToNext();
    }
    c.close();

    return ArrayList;
}
```

with the setonitemclicklistener i get the string of the clicked position. How can i use this string for a new string query like this:

```
lvD.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() { 
             @Override
             public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                  setContentView(R.layout.activity_clicked);
                  String newQuery = "SELECT ROWID _id, linie" + "FROM linie" + "WHERE name =" + lvD.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();                   
                  ArrayList<String> ClickedList = CursorToArray(getApplicationContext(), newQuery, new String[] {});
                  final ListView lvD = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lvClicked);                 
                  ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.activity_clicked, R.id.tvClicked, ClickedList);
                  lvD.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
                  lvD.setDividerHeight(8);

                 }
        });
```

i want the new text to be inside the same listview
basicaly i want to use the string from the first query inside the new query.
im very new to java so please help me.

Answer (score 1):

1. You need to put quotes around name value in the query and put spaces in between as below:

   ```
   String newQuery = "SELECT ROWID _id, linie" + " FROM linie " + 
              " WHERE name = '" + lvD.getItemAtPosition(position).toString()+"'";
   ```
2. Since your `lvd` is final, its directly available inside your method. Remove the line to find below to find it again:

   ```
   //remove this line
   final ListView lvD = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lvClicked);
   ```